# Retrieving HttpServeletRequest parameter inside Spring MVC Model Form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, data-binding

I want to retrieve the value from a field which is not the part of model set at model attribute parameter of spring mvc form tag to my controller. I am confused how to do this. here is my jsp file:

```
    <!-- need to associate this data with invoice id -->



        <table style="border-collapse: collapse;">

            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td><label>ID:</label></td>
                    <td style=" padding-top: .8em; padding-bottom: .8em;"><form:input path="Id" /></td>
                    <td><form:errors class="error" path="Id"/></td>

                </tr>

            **<!-- I want to retrieve the value from form:select tag which do not have path in the model class-->**     

                <tr>
                    <td><label>Customer ID:</label></td>
                    <td><form:select style="width:260px; height:28px;" 
            path=""  id="theCustomerId" onchange="doAjax()">
                        <form:options items="${CustomerIDList}"/>
                        </form:select></td>
```

I have tried HttpServletRequest by setting its name and sending it to controller and retrieve by getparameter but this throws null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: please verify whether you had try to set the name like below.

Try this on the jsp page.

```
 <form:select style="width:260px; height:28px;" 
        path=""  id="theCustomerId" name="theCustomerId" onchange="doAjax()">
```

Then at your controller try this

```
String theCustomerId = request.getParameter("theCustomerId");
```

Comment: No its not a hidden field. Its a field inside a model form. The problem is that the field is not an attribute of a model therefore it doesn't have a path value. I have tried this by setting the name of the field and retrieving it by using get parameter but it thoriws null pointer exception.

Comment: sorry, let me probe more info...
the field inside a model form, is it a display or is inside the form:select, the selector? @AsadJivani

Comment: one more thing, how you pass the field to your controller? Is it the regular form->submit or, the doAjax(). if using doAjax(), then it would not work if you set name in the jsp, rather you need to set it inside doAjax().

Comment: doAjax() for something else, Its submitted like a normal form:form, Yes the field is form:select I want to retrieve its selected value without using model as it is not a part of a model